# List Comprehension Syntax

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've run into a piece of code that reads:

```
queue = [(Xi, Xk) for Xi in csp.vars for Xk in csp.neighbors[Xi]]
```

Is this the equivalent of:

```
for Xi in csp.vars:
    for Xk in csp.neighbors[Xi]:
        queue.append((Xi, Xk))
```

or does this indicate something other than nested for statements?

Comment: No that's exactly what it is. You got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other already pointed out that's exactly what it means.

I also find sometimes confusing using multiple for inside a list-comprehension/genexp, so I usually avoid them. When I use them I usually put every for in a different line, such as:

```
queue = [(Xi, Xk) for Xi in csp.vars
                  for Xk in csp.neighbors[Xi]]
```

Or even indenting:

```
queue = [(Xi, Xk) for Xi in csp.vars
                      for Xk in csp.neighbors[Xi]]
```

This makes it clear which is the inner for loop.

Also, list-comprehension can have an if expression for every for loop, so the complete syntax is something like:

```
queue = [(Xi, Xk) for Xi in csp.vars
                      if condition_one()
                          for Xk in csp.neighbors[Xi]
                              if condition_two()
                                  ... ]
```

Even though I hope you'll never write something like that. The if expression at the end is fine, but mixing it with for makes all too cumbersome and not at all readable.

Comment: At the point where I need to start indenting my list comprehension, it's probably getting too complicated. At that point I would switch to regular code for clarity.

Comment: You are right. I actually only use it when I have two `for` s, or if I have a `for` and an `if` and the expression takes some space(so that the line would be too long). Anything more complicated than thit is better done in the "usual way".

Answer (score 4):

You have it exactly correct. See the [list comprehension documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#list-displays):

> When a list comprehension is supplied, it consists of a single expression followed by at least one `for` clause and zero or more `for` or `if` clauses. In this case, the elements of the new list are those that would be produced by considering each of the `for` or `if` clauses a block, nesting from left to right, and evaluating the expression to produce a list element each time the innermost block is reached.

So your interpretation of the for loop nesting is spot on.